# Some Next.js Links do a full page reload only when deployed on Vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel, next.js14, mantine

I am using Next.js 14 app router on Vercel with Mantine for components. I'm using Next.js `Link`s polymorphically with Mantine components as described [here](https://mantine.dev/guides/next/#nextjs-link-with-polymorphic-components). This was working fine, but in recent deployments for changes that did not touch these `Link`s or update any relevant packages, some of the `Link`s began doing full-page reloads. This happens only in the deployed Vercel site, not using `next dev` or `next build && next start` locally.

You can see the behaviour on the button on the home page of my site: [site](https://rave-reviews.vercel.app/) / [code](https://github.com/jkatofsky/rave-reviews/blob/2da1186d2ba804da59db0c2d9b95e71cad8dee02/app/page.tsx#L11).

However, the issue does not happen in other places. For example, the button on my not-found page: [site](https://rave-reviews.vercel.app/organizers/012432) / [code](https://github.com/jkatofsky/rave-reviews/blob/2da1186d2ba804da59db0c2d9b95e71cad8dee02/app/organizers/%5Bid%5D/not-found.tsx#L9). On the button there, it properly redirects to `/organizers` fully client-side.

Both the home page and the not-found page are statically exported, and these `Link`s are going to the same place, so I don't understand what the difference is that's causing the issue. Does anyone have any idea how an issue like this would start happenning 1) only on the Vercel deployment and 2) only on certain Links?

I've done extensive searching online for this problem, and while it's popped up in quite a few places, I haven't found anything that applies to my project specifically.

PS: While my site is publically deployed, it's a WIP with dummy data, to clear up any confusion

Comment: I believe it has something to do with your `/` & `/organizers` route being `'force-dynamic'`, which is where a `loading.tsx` file would come in handy. Since your `not-found.tsx` is static, the `<Link />` within that component is prefetching that route. 

Helpful links: [Linking & Navigating (prefetching)](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating#2-prefetching) & [Route segments](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config)